# How to subclass Python types inside C extensions?

Tags: python

I know how to define a new type (class) in a Python extension, but is it also possible to define a class that is derived from a Python class? For example, in Python I could define an "extended" list class like so:

```
class xlist(list):
    def xsum(self):
        return sum(self)
```

How would I derive the xlist type from PyList inside a C extension? I wanted to try it out by declaring a PyTypeObject variable and memcpy()ing the contents of the PyList_Type instance into it, but I couldn't figure out how to add the "xsum" method to the new type.